# Side Menu revealcontroller issue with UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I implemented [SWRevealController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) in my application. It has two segues one for slideviewcontroller and viewcontroller.

My slideviewcontroller is UITableViewController, I created a new class MenuTableViewController for use as a custom class of that siderbar(slideview). When I add a MenuTableViewController as a custom class of that view, it isn't shown when i slide a menu. If i leave it blank it's shown. 
The problem is that I want when cell clicked to perform segue identifier or a button clicked, but I don't know where to implement them.

Comment: Keep calm and use AMSlideMenu: https://github.com/arturdev/AMSlideMenu
And do any customization that can fantasize your brain ;)

Comment: Using your component won't solve his problem (but it looks quite good :-) )

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your segue in your tableview's delegate method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];
}
```

You can segue to a proper ViewController depending on indexPath of the selected item inside of that method. Then implement your:

```
 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YourSegueIdentifier"]) 
     {
      DestinatinoVCClass *destinationVC = (DestinatinoVCClass *)segue.destinationViewController;
      //here you can set any public properties of the destinationVC    
     }
 }
```

But in general, as far implementing SWRevealController into your app goes here is a full [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/).

Comment: You can also find some useful examples on github.

Comment: yes but the problem is I dont know where to write this code, cause I dont have a custom class for that UiTableViewController, if I add a custom class to it, then I cant see the view when i press the button to reveal sidebar view.

Comment: Then your problem is not in segue. Your problem is in implementation of your MenuTableViewController. There are multiple reasons for this. Most common is that the delegate methods are not getting called. Update your question and post the code for your MenuTableViewController implementation. Otherwise it is really hard to help you without seeing any code.